# Invalid Argument supplied for foreach after checking everything

Tags: php

I know this has been answered a hundred times over, but this is just plain weird. I have this code:

```
if (isset($vendor_social) && !is_null($vendor_social) && count($vendor_social) > 0) {
    foreach ($vendor_social as $soc) { ... }
}
```

And I still get

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

On that line. How in the world is that happening?

Comment: What does `var_dump` of `$vendor_social` tell you? It might be string type for example and it should be array. You may add `is_array($vendor_social)` to your checks.

Comment: Add a `is_array()` to that check. Only arrays can be supplemented in a `foreach`-loop.

Comment: Ah okay, good point. I will check for that and see what happens. My test data will not throw this error; it only happens in production and I don't want to fill up my hosting service's logs with a bunch of vardumps.

Comment: It does sound like `$vendor_social` isn't what you think it is. Remember that `count` always returns 1 for strings.

Comment: @max, if you add an answer mentioning string type, i will mark it correct. that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be string type for example and it should be an array. You may add `is_array($vendor_social)` to your checks.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the `$vendor_social` is not an array, or more precisely not Traversable.

For example, a non empty string will satisfy your condition but failed foreach.